# Verificar encoding de um XML

Tags: java, xml

Eu preciso processar uma série de arquivos XML. Uma das exigências é que o *encoding* seja *UTF-8*. Qualquer outro tipo de *enconding* deve ser rejeitado.

Isso é aceito:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Isso não

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Qualquer outra coisa diferente de UTF-8" ?>
```

Estou usando a **javax.xml** para ler, validar e processar meus arquivos mas não é mandatório. Se conhecerem outra *lib* ou método que faça isso ótimo!

Já revirei a internet e não consegui encontrar absolutamente nada parecido. Algum de vocês já precisou fazer isso? Como resolveram?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun coloquei mais detalhes, mas a lib que estou usando não faz muita diferença, pode ser qualquer uma :p

Comment: Edgar, é que para cada uma das bibliotecas existe uma forma que é melhor que a outra por se integrar melhor com o restante do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta verificar o *encoding* pelo método `getEncoding()` presente no `XMLStreamReader`:

**Abaixo um exemplo completo:**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class LeitorXML  {
    public boolean isUTF8(InputStream entrada) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(entrada);
        System.out.println(xmlReader.getEncoding());
        return xmlReader.getEncoding().equalsIgnoreCase("UTF-8");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeitorXML reader = new LeitorXML();
        try {
            URL url  = LeitorXML.class.getClassLoader().getResource("exemplo2.xml"); 
            InputStream strm=null;
            strm = url.openStream();
            if(reader.isUTF8(strm)){
                System.out.println("O documento é UTF-8");
            }else{
                System.out.println("O documento não é UTF-8");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

exemplo.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <item date="2009">
    <mode>1</mode>
  </item>
  <item date="2010">
    <mode>2</mode>
  </item>
</config>
```

exemplo2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<config>
  <item date="2009">
    <mode>1</mode>
  </item>
  <item date="2010">
    <mode>2</mode>
  </item>
</config>
```